# Data type for a variable that can be different types

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to C# but seem to have noticed a limitation from what I am wanting to do with my code.

I have a class which i want to store a reference to other classes which i plan to store in a list. Something like this:

```
myList.Add(new Node(1,1,referenceToClassA));
myList.Add(new Node(1,2,referenceToClassB));
```

So my class would look like this:

```
public class Node : IHeapItem<Node> { //IHeapItem is for a heap i use for pathfinding

  public int x;
  public int y;
  public ??? reference;

  // constructor
  public Node(int a, int b , ??? r){
    x = a;
    y = b;
    reference = r;
  }

 // other unrelated stuff
}
```

So as you can probably guess, i have no idea what data type `reference` would be in my class given that it could be assigned to different classes.

I can't seem to find if there is a data type that is flexible for this in C# (i started in JavaScript so am not used to strict behavior on variable types).

What are my options here, what data type should I use, or will i have to implement this in a totally different way?

Hope you can help.

Comment: Giving a quick google, perhaps [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) could be a starting point? I'm fairly new to C# myself so I'm not 100%

Comment: @Jhecht Dynamic will create a variable that can adapt. However, I would advise against this if you're not sure what you're doing. If the nodes will have the same type of object in each one of them, you can create a typed object list `List<Node<CLASSA>> myList;`

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the heads up @Tom

Comment: `dynamic` is not an option. Unity uses an old version of Mono (2.6.4 I think) that doesn't have all features of C# 4, `dynamic` is one that's been left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you only have one type of item in each list, then you could use this:

```
public class Node<T> : IHeapItem<Node> { //IHeapItem is for a heap i use for pathfinding

  public int x;
  public int y;
  public T reference;

  // constructor
  public Node(int a, int b , T r){
    x = a;
    y = b;
    reference = r;
  }
```

// other unrelated stuff
}

If you don't know what you're going to get, and you will have more than one item in a list, then you're forced to use `object`.  With a little reflection, that can work out pretty well.

It is also possible that you will have sets of different items, each set could implement the same interface, then that interface could be what you hold in the list.

Comment: What do you mean by one `type of item` in each list?

Comment: It only matters if you're trying to build a list of `Node<T>`. He's saying each instance has to use the same type for `T`.

Comment: So you mean my lists would be `myList.Add(new Node<T>(1,1,ReferenceToA);` and not a mixture of `Node` and `Node<T>`?

Comment: When you are instantiating a `Node<T>`, replace T with the type you want. For example, if the reference was a `string`, you'd say `myList.Add(new Node<string>(1, 1, "foo"));` Of course this assumes you know what `T` is at compile time. If you don't, you'll have to use `dynamic` (not something C# usually encourages).

Comment: @PlanetLotus did you mean to put `<string>` when referencing a `int`? Because that has really confused me now xD

Comment: Brain fart :) edited. Sorry about that. Really easy to lose sight of my example in this tiny comment box with no line breaks.

Comment: @PlanetLotus Ok there is one technical issue, if I don't need a reference i was going to overload the constructor. So what would that make the node for creating it? `myList.Add(new Node<null>(5,5));`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111268/discussion-between-planetlotus-and-dave).

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create a generic, use `T` as the parameter type.

If you use `T` as the parameter type, you'll have to modify your class to be `Node<T>` as well.

Otherwise, you could use `dynamic`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a class called Object that can reference any other class. If you want to make it just to a little group of classes, you may want to create an abstract class or an interface.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's most likely because a) the code in the question is using generics, and there is a better solution than Object for that, and b) *dynamic* would be a better suggestion than just *Object*. This might be a great answer for a far earlier version of .Net (like 1.0 or 2.0), but not for current versions.

Comment: I know generics pretty well, but for a beginer, generics are a pain in the ass. So I just sugested Object. The old Object still works. Just in case you don't know.

Comment: @KenWhite don't forget i tagged `unity3d` which i believe uses an older .Net version but i don't know which one.

Comment: I didn't down vote, though would welcome a code example to your answer! As i am new to abstract classes and interfaces. I'll upvote to remove the negative.

Comment: @Dave: Read the first three words of my previous comment.

Comment: @Dave: You asked *me* to remember what you asked. I pointed out I wasn't the one that downvoted. Never mind. I'm sorry I tried to explain what the possible problems were that might have caused *someone else* to downvote this answer.

Comment: @KenWhite i was saying that because my question was related to unity3d which uses an older .Net. Had nothing to do with the vote system stuff! :P